# AWS: How to push event viewer logs from a windows based EC2 machine

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch

I have hosted my web api application on a windows server in AWS EC2. Sometimes I get 503 service unavailable error while accessing my web api. So I am trying to figure out a way to push the event viewer logs from the ec2 to cloudwatch. Is it possible to do that? Or the only way is to RDP into the EC2 and check event viewer logs?

Comment: Seems like pretty valid use case for Cloudwatch Agent. Did you check this?
https://medium.com/tensult/sending-windows-2012-logs-to-cloudwatch-5c7010582461

Comment: Haven't tried it yet. Will give it a try. Thanks.